# Initial-boundary value problem for the damped wave equation with nonlinear source (in bounded domains)

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, hyperbolic-pde, wave-equation

It is well known that the initial-value problem for the wave equation on $\mathbb R^N$ can be studied by means of Fourier transform.

What reference presents well-posedness results and qualitative properties (decay, speed of propagation) of the damped wave equation with nonlinear source on a **bounded domain**?

What are the differences with respect to the corresponding results in the whole space?